# How to avoid Get-QADUser queries to return multiple property strings with PowerShell 2.0

Tags: string, powershell, active-directory, ldap, quest

I am using *Get-QADUser* and *.DirectoryEntry.FirstName* in PowerShell 2.0 to make multiple LDAP queries and return strings. These multiple calls are slow.  How could I make one *Get-QADUser* LDAP query only and create strings from select properties.

Example:

```
    ADD-PSSnapin Quest.Activeroles.ADManagement
    $searchDomainFrom = 'domain.net/OUPath/Users'
    $user = UserName

    $FirstName = (Get-QADUser -SearchRoot $searchDomainFrom $user).DirectoryEntry.FirstName
    $LastName = (Get-QADUser -SearchRoot $searchDomainFrom $user).DirectoryEntry.LastName
    $Email = (Get-QADUser -SearchRoot $searchDomainFrom $user).DirectoryEntry.Email
    $Supervisor = (Get-QADUser -SearchRoot $searchDomainFrom $user).DirectoryEntry.Manager
    $OfficeLocation = (Get-QADUser -SearchRoot $searchDomainFrom $user).DirectoryEntry.Office
    $PhoneNumber = (Get-QADUser -SearchRoot $searchDomainFrom $user).DirectoryEntry.PhoneNumber
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the query once and then gets your strings from the object that's returned the first time.

```
$Current = Get-QADUser -SearchRoot $searchDomainFrom $user
$FirstName = $Current.DirectoryEntry.FirstName
$LastName = $Current.DirectoryEntry.LastName
$Email = $Current.DirectoryEntry.Email
$Supervisor = $Current.DirectoryEntry.Manager
$OfficeLocation = $Current.DirectoryEntry.Office
$PhoneNumber = $Current.DirectoryEntry.PhoneNumber
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work for _$FirstName_ and _$LastName_.  _$Email_ returns a Method Member Type. How do I get that to return a string?

Comment: I don't use the Quest addons, but I assume it should have an `.Email.ToString()` method that you could try.

Comment: You're my hero. It works as  _$Email = $CurrentUser.Email.ToString()_